# Santa Cruz Blur linkage maintence

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, full-suspension

How much maintenance and what is it specifically that needs attention on 2006 - 2010 Santa Cruz Bur VPP rear linkage mountain bikes?

Im looking to buy a used Blur XC, but I hear they need a lot of upkeep. Just wondering what. Is it just a lube and clean situation? or replacing bushings on a yearly basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No more than any other full floater.

- The bearings are sealed so they should only need replacing every few years or so.
- The bushes usually last a year, but you can feel their state by any 'knocking' when you take pressure off the wheels, or by trying to bend the swingarm laterally.

Stripping down the frame and regreasing the pivots won't do any harm, but certainly isn't necessary - I find it just makes getting the bearings out easier when they need replacing.  Admittedly, after a wash I put a few drips of thick 3-in-1 oil inbetween each pivot - truthfully I have no idea if this does anything, but it probably stops water sitting in the bearing cavities for long periods.

As for any other sealed bearing do **not** spray GT85, WD40, or any other water displacing fluid into them.  They come pre-greased, and if the seal fails, it needs replacing.

Comment: Perfect. thanks. Just didnt want to get into a bike that needed more upkeep than other full suspensions I have had in the past. I had an Intense 5.5 EVP with the same creaky rear end, so im kind of used to it. Just been on hard tails the past few years.

Comment: A mate of mine has a Blur 4X from about '06, and he's abused the hell out of it - the frame itself is still fine after no maintenance whatsoever.  One year he even snapped his forks after a nose diving a 10ft drop in Morzine...